# Select within select with a case "twist"

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

```
SELECT 
        (select CASE 
                WHEN DP_ART_HEAD.KPP_KAT_ART_COD = 'M1' THEN 
                    ROUND(DP_ART_LINES.XONDRIKH - DP_ART_LINES.XONDRIKH * DP_ART_LINES.POSOSTO_EKP_PROT / 100, 2) 
                WHEN DP_ART_HEAD.KPP_KAT_ART_COD = 'M2' THEN 
                    DP_ART_LINES.TIM_MON 
                ELSE 
                    DP_ART_LINES.TIM_MON 
                end AS 'NIKOS' 
        FROM DP_ART_LINES 
        JOIN AP_APO_HEAD ON DP_ART_LINES.EID_CODE = AP_APO_HEAD.EID_CODE 
                        AND DP_ART_LINES.KPP_APO_CODE = AP_APO_HEAD.KPP_APO_CODE 
        JOIN DP_ART_HEAD ON DP_ART_LINES.RN_DP_ART_HEAD = DP_ART_HEAD.RN_DP_ART_HEAD 
        WHERE DP_ART_LINES.EID_CODE = AP_APO_HEAD.EID_CODE
    ), 
    DP_ART_HEAD.KPP_KAT_ART_COD, 
    DP_ART_LINES.EID_CODE AS 'Κωδικός', 
    AP_APO_HEAD.EID_PERIGR AS 'Είδος', 
    DP_ART_LINES.POSOT AS 'Ποσότης', 
    DP_ART_LINES.XONDRIKH AS 'Τιμή Χονδρικής', 
    DP_ART_LINES.POSOSTO_EKP_PROT AS 'Έκπτωση', 
    DP_ART_LINES.FL_DORO AS 'Δώρο' 
FROM DP_ART_LINES 
JOIN AP_APO_HEAD ON DP_ART_LINES.EID_CODE = AP_APO_HEAD.EID_CODE 
                AND DP_ART_LINES.KPP_APO_CODE = AP_APO_HEAD.KPP_APO_CODE 
JOIN DP_ART_HEAD ON DP_ART_LINES.RN_DP_ART_HEAD = DP_ART_HEAD.RN_DP_ART_HEAD
```

the end result is

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Apparently I'm trying to shove a bunch of values from the case statement in a single value receptor.
Is there (of course there is) a better way to go about it?

Comment: Please add some sample data, i.e. include some data using `Create table` and `Insert into` with sample data, which enables someone to actually run your code. This is so people can understand the code better, and do better test. 

Also, what is your expected return? What result set would you expect?

Comment: Well, the error message is very clear, your subquery returned more then one value. However, It's kinda hard to answer without sample data and desired results, so please edit your question to include them.

Comment: You're going to want to correlate that subquery to the outer query by adding to the were clause of the subquery. Something like `WHERE DP_ART_LINES.EID_CODE = AP_APO_HEAD.EID_CODE AND DP_ART_LINES.EID_CODE = outerQuery.EID_CODE` where outerQuery would be the alias for DP_ART_LINES for the outer query

Answer (score 0):

The subquery can return multiple rows. You can prevent this with top 1.

Also I prefer outer apply over select in select.

Try the code below.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN DP_ART_HEAD.KPP_KAT_ART_COD = 'M1' 
        THEN ROUND(DP_ART_LINES.XONDRIKH - DP_ART_LINES.XONDRIKH * DP_ART_LINES.POSOSTO_EKP_PROT / 100, 2) 
        ELSE DP_ART_LINES.TIM_MON 
        end AS 'NIKOS' , 
    DP_ART_HEAD.KPP_KAT_ART_COD, 
    DP_ART_LINES.EID_CODE AS 'Κωδικός', 
    AP_APO_HEAD.EID_PERIGR AS 'Είδος', 
    DP_ART_LINES.POSOT AS 'Ποσότης', 
    DP_ART_LINES.XONDRIKH AS 'Τιμή Χονδρικής', 
    DP_ART_LINES.POSOSTO_EKP_PROT AS 'Έκπτωση', 
    DP_ART_LINES.FL_DORO AS 'Δώρο' 
FROM DP_ART_LINES 
JOIN AP_APO_HEAD ON DP_ART_LINES.EID_CODE = AP_APO_HEAD.EID_CODE 
                AND DP_ART_LINES.KPP_APO_CODE = AP_APO_HEAD.KPP_APO_CODE 
JOIN DP_ART_HEAD ON DP_ART_LINES.RN_DP_ART_HEAD = DP_ART_HEAD.RN_DP_ART_HEAD
```

Comment: wow. I can't begin to express how grateful i am. i hoped for an eventual answer but so much help in such a short time is just staggering. Thank you all so much for your immediate response and the willingness to assist. I apologize for the lack of expected data, a fact that i did not consider. in my defence this is actually the first time i used stackoverflow. I will be sure to be more structured and provide more researched data in the future. That having been said. @Peter, your response was right on the spot solved the issue completely, save for some mathematical function.

Comment: Im unsure how i can provide readable info on how the output is supposed to look like. Basically if the (Prod Category) KPP_KAT_ART_COD = 'M1' then you need to reduce DP_ART_LINES.XONDRIKH (Retail Price) by a percentage % equal to DP_ART_LINES.POSOSTO_EKP_PROT.(%discount) We're trying to apply a multicategory discount to all our products (M1, M2, M3) and the system should calculate the retail price based on that profile. If that helps. Executing the code i get the same value on every row for the NIKOS column which is what the top 1 does i imagine.The new column should have the discounted value.

Comment: @KonstantinosNtikas You should have another look at `WHERE DP_ART_LINES.EID_CODE = AP_APO_HEAD.EID_CODE`. What are you trying to do here? You already have `ON DP_ART_LINES.EID_CODE = AP_APO_HEAD.EID_CODE` which is doing the same thing. When you use the same table multiple times, you should use alliasses

Comment: I've updated the answer. I don't think you need the subquery.

Comment: And it works perfectly and i apparently overcomplicated things. Thank you again for your support and amazing response time :)